# Slack Cli - How has it been broken after upgrade?

Tags: windows, slack

After an upgrade on slack-cli, I can't execute slack command, because of a missing path.

I upgraded slack-cli from 2.9.1 to 2.19.0. After that, when I try to execute a command, I have always the same message, even with slack doctor.

`> There was an error while reading the Slack Configuration file (`slack.json`) or running the` get-hooks` hook (sdk_config_load_error)

Error Details:

1: Command for 'GetHooks' returned an error: exec: "pwsh": executable file not found in %!!(MISSING)P(MISSING)ATH%!!(MISSING)

(MISSING) (sdk_hook_invocation_failed)

Suggestion: Run `slack doctor` to check that your system dependencies are up-to-date.`

The slack.json file was not modified, so I guess the path through this slack.json file has been erased, but I d'ont find how to modifiy it.

I tried to uninstall/reinstall slack-cli but it hasn't solve the problem.

I expect to be able to use slack-cli again

Comment: My problem has been solved by installing powershell 7. Thanks to GeneralPatton on this forum https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D5Hq00009l8UtWKAU/after-an-upgrade-on-slackcli-i-cant-execute-slack-command-because-of-a-missing-path?language=en_US&t=1710753115650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update the version of PowerShell you are currently using. The latter versions of the Slack CLI rely on the `pwsh` being available, which currently is not exposed in the version of PowerShell you are running.

This issue was raised in the Slack Community previously and this was the fix. Product/Devs are aware and looking to update the documentation.

EDIT: "The minimum supported PowerShell version as of Slack CLI v2.18.0 is v6.0. If you attempt to use an older version of PowerShell, you may encounter errors reading the configuration file (slack.json) or running the get hooks hook."

From - https://api.slack.com/automation/quickstart